# Dynamically load implementation class for a webservice

Tags: xml, web-services, resteasy

I have an interface as given below, what I need to do is that I need to load the implementation class dynamically. That is I need to load different classes for the same interface in different situations.

```
@Path("/service")
@WebService
public interface Authentication {

    @Path("/t/login")
    @POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @WebMethod
    public LoginRsp loginUser(@WebParam(name = "login") LoginRq login);
}
```

My current implementation class is as given below, I need to load another implementation class for the same request dynamically overriding my default class. Is it possible to do so?

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "service.ws.Authentication")
public class AuthenticationImpl implements Authentication {
-
-
}
```

And also, is it possible to set `endpointInterface` through an xml file?

Comment: Why not have a single Authentication resource and then within the loginUser method use a factory pattern to create the appropriate backend service call you need?

Comment: JPA seemingly lacking in the question, hence suggest you untag it. No point in random tagging of any technology used elsewhere in your app.

Comment: @NeilStockton, You are correct, that was my mistake.